# How to access environment variables in an Expect script?

Tags: environment-variables, expect

I would like to access the PATH environment variable inside an expect script.

How can I achieve that ?

My actual script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 300
send "echo $PATH\r"
```

and its ouput is :

```
can't read "PATH": no such variable
    while executing
"send "echo $PATH\r""
```

Comment: Very nuanced issue. I struggled with it for many hours.
Thanks for asking the right questions.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Expect is an extension of [Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk). Tcl access enviroment variables via the global [`env` array](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M4):

```
send_user "$env(PATH)\n"
```

Answer (score 20):

You can use the global env array by using:

```
$::env(PATH)
```

This notion will also work inside procedures.

Comment: This should be approved as the correct answer, it works

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the target $PATH variable, then you must escape the "$" :

exp_sent -- echo "\$PATH\r"

Answer (score 1):

Both `$::env(PATH)` and `$env(PATH)` work well. The former is ok also inside other scripts (like `expect -c "..."`, the latter is more "programming style".