# how to execute command in expect condition statement

Tags: bash, expect

When I try to use variable in an expect condition statement, it turns out that it doesn't work.

result:

```
qianyu@ubuntu:~/bin$ ./expectinstall.sh iotop
spawn sudo apt-get install iotop
[sudo] password for qianyu:
```

my script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
set password qianyu
set app [lindex $argv 0]
set username `whoami`

spawn sudo apt-get install $app
expect {
"*password for ${username}*" { send "${password}\r" }
}
expect eof
```

--update--

I find the problem of my script is not getting the username, but setting the username by command in `` `...` ``. I changed it to `[exec ...]`, and it works well.

corrected script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1
set password qianyu
set app [lindex $argv 0]
set username [exec whoami]

spawn sudo apt-get install -y $app 
expect {
"*password for ${username}*" { send "${password}\r"; }
}
expect eof
```

Comment: See: [How to use bash script variables in expect conditional statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11131318/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus, i didn't find any clue from the answer before i post this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access environment variables in an Expect script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695474/how-to-access-environment-variables-in-an-expect-script)

Answer (score 0):

Prefix it with `$env(...)`
As an example, to use `$HOME`, do this
`$env(HOME)`